# Multi line paragraph adding excess padding in flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a little promo banner that consists of flex container (pictured in light blue), a flex item that is itself a flex container which holds a paragraph and finally a second flex item which holds a description.

I want the first flex item to be flexible to a maximum of say 40% and then word wrap when it exceeds that length.

The problem is that when it does, it adds an exceedingly long padding to the paragraph which pushes the length of it and throws the design off balance.

I'm unsure if it is a flexbox issue or a paragraph length issue.

**Single line - flex is fine**

[image]

**Multi line - weird padding**

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
.infoBox {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #00aaee;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 14px 45px 14px 27px;
  margin: 6px 0px 40px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 45px 45px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 45px 45px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 45px 45px 0px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.infoBox .title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0 auto;
  -moz-box-flex: 0 auto;
  -ms-flex-flex: 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 auto;
  -o-flex: 0 auto;
  flex: 0 auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 27px;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 40%;
}
.infoBox .title p {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-right: 27px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -o-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoBox">
  <div class="title"><p>Behind the scenes</p></div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Quick-hit reviews of our favorite apps, games and other things no    mobile user should be without.</p><p>www.test.com</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add a full border around your paragraph. You'll notice that there is no *excess padding* being added. It's just the container scaling its size independently of any wrapping going on inside, which is how CSS works.

Comment: One thing that *may* help is adding `text-align: right` to the paragraph container (`.title`).

Comment: Sorry, Michael_B. Didn't see that.

I ended up adding the line break dynamically in PHP and got the correct padding I was looking for. CSS alone was not cutting it.